# Quality of default audio driver for a USB DAC

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hardware

I have read HiFime UAE23HD USB DAC has better sound using ASIO driver than by not using a separate driver in Windows. What kind of quality I can expect in Linux when compared to Windows? They tell you do not need to install separate device drivers for it, but do I get the full potential of the device then?

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of the Windows USB audio driver were limited to 16-bit samples at 48 kHz; installing a vendor-specific driver (ASIO or not) was a workaround to make better sample formats available for a device that supports them.

The Linux driver does not have this limitation. (Neither do [recent Windows versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/usb-2-0-audio-drivers).)

Comment: There seems to be limit of 24-bit samples at 96kHz without drivers. But I think that does not explain the hearable improvement in sound quality when using ASIO drivers. https://hifimediy.com/Sabre-9018-DAC

Comment: As long as the same sample values are sent over USB, there is nothing the driver can do that would be able to affect the sound quality. I doubt that those reports about the ASIO driver would survive an ABX test. (You could do you own tests with a Windows machine.)